# Proof by induction proof by using positive numbers n

Tags: calculus, induction

I was able to prove by induction, that for $k=1$, $\frac{d}{dx} e^{kx} = ke^{kx}$.

Assuming the rule is true for $k=n$, I am supposed to show that the rule is true for $ k = n+1$

I have no idea where to even start with this.

Comment: look at the hints below... if two persons gives same hint at a time, that should tell what should be obvious thought one would look for in this case :)

Comment: I do not think that you used induction to show $\frac d{dx}e^x=e^x$ as you state in your first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $${d\over dx}(e^{(1)x})=e^x=(1)e^{(1)x},$$ the statement is true for $k=1$. Assume that ${d\over dx}(e^{nx})=ne^{nx}$ for an arbitrary positive integer n. We show that $${d\over dx}(e^{(n+1)x})=(n+1)e^{(n+1)x}.$$  Consider $${d\over dx}(e^{(n+1)x})={d\over dx}(e^{nx}\cdot e^x).$$ By the product rule we have $$e^x\cdot {d\over dx}(e^{nx})+e^{nx}\cdot {d\over dx}(e^x).$$ Using the induction hypothesis ${d\over dx}(e^{nx})=ne^{nx}$ we obtain $$e^x\cdot ne^{nx}+e^{nx}\cdot e^x$$ which becomes $$ne^{nx+x}+e^{nx+x}.$$ Factoring, we see the desired result $$(n+1)e^{(n+1)x}.$$ Thus by the Principle of Mathematical Induction ${d\over dx}(e^{kx})=ke^{kx}$ for every positive integer $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Try the product rule.  $e^{(n+1)x}=e^{nx}e^x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $e^{(n+1)x}$ as $e^{nx}e^x$ and use the product rule.